# Running custom tests with stack and hpack

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to write my own test framework and I can't even get started. Here is my directory structure:

```
 $ tree
.
├── prj1
│   ├── package.yaml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── Module.hs
│   └── test-dir
│       └── TheTest.hs
└── stack.yaml
```

And each of the files is:

**stack.yaml**

```
resolver: lts-16.11
packages:
  - prj1
```

**package.yaml**

```
name: prj1
version: 0.1
maintainer: fakedrake
category: Test

library:
  source-dirs: src
  exposed-modules: []
  dependencies:
      - base

tests:
  prj1-tests:
    main: TheTest.hs
    source-dirs: test-dir
    dependencies:
      - base
```

**TheTest.hs**

```
module TheTest () where


main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Test passes!"
```

**Module.hs**

```
module Module () where
```

But when I run `stack test` I get

```
$ stack test
prj1> configure (lib + test)
Configuring prj1-0.1...
prj1> build (lib + test)
Preprocessing library for prj1-0.1..
Building library for prj1-0.1..
[1 of 2] Compiling Module
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_prj1
Preprocessing test suite 'prj1-tests' for prj1-0.1..
Building test suite 'prj1-tests' for prj1-0.1..
[1 of 2] Compiling Paths_prj1
[2 of 2] Compiling TheTest

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.

--  While building package prj1-0.1 using:
      /my/home/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.0.1.0 build lib:prj1 test:prj1-tests --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Progress 1/2
```

Comment: IIRC the module name of an executable has to be `Main`. So in `TheTest.hs` you should change `module TheTest` to `module Main`, and probably also expose the `main` entrypoint.

Comment: You can probably check the module name rules in the Haskell report.

Answer (score 1):

The convention for HPack / Stack based projects is that the main entry point for the tests resides in a file `test/Spec.hs`

So just rename your module `TheTest.hs` to `Spec.hs` and also set `main: Spec.hs` in the `tests:` section of the `package.yaml` and everything should be fine.

You could also produce a minimal HPack / Stack based project scaffold including test-suite with `stack new prj1` as a starting point.

The nice thing about Spec.hs as main entry point is that it allow to have automatic lookup
of test cases.

To enable this just place a single line in Spec.hs:

```hs
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF hspec-discover #-}
```

This pragma will find all module that follow the naming convention

`*Spec.hs`

and then you can have individual Test module like `ReverseSpec.hs`:

```hs
module ReverseSpec where

import           Test.Hspec

-- `main` is here so that this module can be run from GHCi on its own.  It is
-- not needed for automatic spec discovery.
main :: IO ()
main = hspec spec

-- this is the actual entry point for tests
spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "reverse" $ do
    it "is inverse to itself" $
      property $ \str -> (reverse . reverse) str `shouldBe` (id str :: String)
```

---

If you really want to roll your own Test framework, you can edit your file `TheTest.hs` as follows:

1. Without a module clause:

```hs
-- module TheTest () where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Test passes!"
```

2. or with a modified module clause:

```hs
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Test passes!"
```

This will work with both `cabal test` and `stack test`.

Comment: I intentionally used these names to make it clear that I am trying to build my own testing framework. As far as I can tell from the documentation what you mention are HSpec conventions rather than stack conventions. Am I mistaken?

Comment: If you really want to roll your own, you can just place `module Main where` at the top of your `TheTest.hs` file. (Of course it would be better to then also call the file "Main.hs", but it will work this way also...

Comment: Maybe it's worth having a look at https://github.com/NorfairKing/sydtest. That's quite a new testing framework which tries to incorporate many best practises from older approaches.